# Can I use a CSS class to style a div inside an iframe to be the parent window's width and hight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my div to go fullscreen.
I have a structure similar to the following and my method works when my div is outside an iframe but I can't get rid of the iframe.

html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe>
            <div id="contentDiv">Content</div>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.Maximized{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
}
```

When a user fullscreens the browser my content div should go fullscreen as well.
In my `fullscreen-on` event I do the following

```
$('#contentDiv').addClass('Maximized');
```

However the div fills the iframe and not the main window.

Is it possible to make my div go full screen just by adding classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll need to make the iframe go full screen as well.

As far as the contents of the iframe are concerned the iframe is the window, so going full screen inside the iframe will only make it the size of the iframe.  But if you resize the iframe to be full window, then its contents can be full as well, provided you have no border, padding or margins on your iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" >
<div id="contentDiv">Content</div>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `iframe` needs a `src`. You can't directly access the CSS of your `iframe` through the `parent` window, but that shouldn't matter in your case. Your code should look more like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      iframe{
        height:100%; width:100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <iframe src='content.html'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```